# react loadable is not working with css module

Tags: reactjs, react-loadable

I am trying to do code split with react-loadable library. It indeed splits code base on the point that I setup. However, all the css file is included into .js file which is not rendering in server side.

In client side, it need to fetch like 100 individual css file to get all the css file which will slow down site by a lot(we at http1).

How not to bundle in to react loadable ?